# Непонятное поведение fbclient при подключению к удаленному серверу firebird

Tags: firebird

**Доброго времени суток!**

Столкнулся с очередной непонятной ситуацией при работе с firebird server 2.1. Программа производит подключение к удаленному firebird серверу через клиентскую библиотеку fbclient.dll, однако использует настройки подключения локального firebird сервера.

Долго ломал голову, почему не могу подключиться к удаленному серверу, пока не запустил процессмонитор, и не обнаружил, что, по какой-то причине, клиентская часть ищет установленный сервер на локальной машине, и после обнаружения его, считывает его настройки, в частности порт для поключения (на локальной машине он намеренно прописан как 3055), после чего ломится на удаленный сервер по данному порту (на удаленном сервере порт используется по умолчанию 3050).

Не могу найти информации почему такое происходит, и с какой целью такое поведение сделано у клиентской библиотеке. Ну и как это поведение обойти? Мне нужно, чтобы программа обращалась на удаленный сервер корректно по заданном порту.

Может кто сталкивался с таким поведением? Что нужно сделать.

**Спасибо за помощь**

Comment: какая среда разработки/язык программирования используется? Какие компоненты/классы/фреймворки используются?

Comment: @Kovadim, vc++, fbclient из поставки сервера. Версия 2.1.1.17910. Программа написана с использованием mfc, но это здесь не причем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на данный вопрос нашелся на [ibaseforum.ru](http://ibaseforum.ru/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=5718).

Как я понял, ответ был от представителя из ряда разработчиков сервера, потому процитирую его здесь, вдруг кому пригодится:

> На пальцах:
>
> - сервер ищет firebird.conf в каталоге установки (на один каталог выше самого сервера) и НЕ использует запись в реестре.
> - клиент сначала смотрит в реестр и, если там нет соотв. записи, то ищет firebird.conf так же как и сервер.
>
> Алгоритм поиска конфигурации я на пальцах показал. Он меняться не будет.
>
> - Запись в реестре "мешает"? Убери её, серверу она не нужна.
> - Запись в реестре нужна ? Сделай так, чтобы она указывала на другой firebird.conf, там где не изменён порт.
> - Или используй переменную среды FIREBIRD в приложении.